# How to find centripetal acceleration of a 2D object like disc

Tags: rotational-dynamics, acceleration, centripetal-force

I am able to find centripetal acceleration of point object  but a question came in my test which asked us to find:

The centripetal acceleration of a disc (a 2D object), revolving around its center with uniform angular velocity and having a radius $r$

I am very puzzled, I am not sure if centripetal acceleration is even defined for 2D objects

Please if anyone can provide me a source on internet or give the derivation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> I am not sure if centripetal acceleration is even defined for 2D
> objects

Trying to define centripetal acceleration for an entire 2D disc makes little sense.

For **any point** on the disc:

$$\mathbf{a_c}=-\omega^2\mathbf{r}$$

But it's nonsensical to try and define this for the entire disc.